# emsdk10 won't install properly on windows 11

Tags: webassembly

I've followed the [instructions](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html#verifying-the-installation) around 20 times now in slightly different ways and I can't for the life of me get emcc to compile my code.

Their website says to type the following 3 commands for windows:

```
emsdk install latest
emsdk activate latest
emsdk_env.bat
```

I started with PowerShell, which won't recognize emsdk or emcc after running the 3 commands at all.
I tried CMD, which say it's missing clang to run emcc (which is better than nothing). However, CLang won't activate when I run `emsdk activate latest`. Or more specifically:

```
emcc: error: clang executable not found at `"My path to emsdk"/emsdk/upstream/bin\clang.exe`
```

And that path has the following files
[image: Files in Bin]

When I run `emsdk list` directly after running `emsdk activate latest` in CMD, I get the following:

```
The *recommended* precompiled SDK download is 3.1.13 (bc44364b561cfde15c243a54e3b96ea12d7ea284).

To install/activate it, use one of:
         latest                  [default (llvm) backend]
         latest-fastcomp         [legacy (fastcomp) backend]

Those are equivalent to installing/activating the following:
         3.1.13             INSTALLED
         3.1.13-fastcomp

All recent (non-legacy) installable versions are:
         3.1.13    INSTALLED
         3.1.12
         3.1.11    
         3.1.10
         3.1.9
         3.1.8
         3.1.7    
         3.1.6
         3.1.5
         3.1.4
         3.1.3    
         3.1.2
         3.1.1
         3.1.0
         3.1.13-asserts    
         3.1.12-asserts
         3.1.11-asserts
         3.1.10-asserts
         3.1.9-asserts
         3.1.8-asserts    
         3.1.7-asserts
         3.1.6-asserts
         3.1.5-asserts
         3.1.4-asserts    
         3.1.3-asserts
         3.1.2-asserts
         3.1.1-asserts
         3.1.0-asserts    
         3.0.1
         3.0.0
         3.0.1-asserts
         3.0.0-asserts    
         2.0.34
         2.0.33
         2.0.32
         2.0.31    
         2.0.30
         2.0.29
         2.0.28
         2.0.27    
         2.0.26
         2.0.25
         2.0.24
         2.0.23    
         2.0.22
         2.0.21
         2.0.20
         2.0.19    
         2.0.18
         2.0.17
         2.0.16
         2.0.15    
         2.0.14
         2.0.13
         2.0.12
         2.0.11    
         2.0.10
         2.0.9
         2.0.8
         2.0.7    
         2.0.6
         2.0.5
         2.0.4
         2.0.3    
         2.0.2
         2.0.1
         2.0.0
         2.0.31-asserts    
         2.0.30-asserts
         2.0.29-lto
         2.0.28-lto
         2.0.27-lto    
         2.0.26-lto
         2.0.23-lto
         2.0.20-lto
         2.0.19-lto
         1.40.1    
         1.40.0
         1.39.20
         1.39.19
         1.39.18    
         1.39.17
         1.39.16
         1.39.15
         1.39.14    
         1.39.13
         1.39.12
         1.39.11
         1.39.10    
         1.39.9
         1.39.8
         1.39.7
         1.39.6    
         1.39.5
         1.39.4
         1.39.3
         1.39.2
         1.39.1    
         1.39.0
         1.38.48
         1.38.47
         1.38.46    
         1.38.45
         1.38.44
         1.38.43    
         1.38.42
         1.38.41
         1.38.40
         1.38.39    
         1.38.38
         1.38.37
         1.38.36
         1.38.35
         1.38.34    
         1.38.33

The additional following precompiled SDKs are also available for download:
    *    sdk-releases-upstream-bc44364b561cfde15c243a54e3b96ea12d7ea284-64bit   INSTALLED
         sdk-releases-upstream-6b8f75967b5d37fa898d217b560d571694eb5b13-64bit
         sdk-releases-fastcomp-edf24e7233e0def312a08cc8dcec63a461155da1-64bit
         sdk-releases-fastcomp-536568644fd67d53778f6111fdd5f64ad3f4c539-64bit
         sdk-fastcomp-1.38.30-64bit
         sdk-fastcomp-1.38.31-64bit

The following SDKs can be compiled from source:
         sdk-upstream-main-64bit
         sdk-fastcomp-tag-1.38.30-64bit
         sdk-fastcomp-tag-1.38.31-64bit

The following precompiled tool packages are available for download:
    (*)    releases-upstream-bc44364b561cfde15c243a54e3b96ea12d7ea284-64bit     INSTALLED
           releases-upstream-6b8f75967b5d37fa898d217b560d571694eb5b13-64bit
           releases-fastcomp-edf24e7233e0def312a08cc8dcec63a461155da1-64bit
           releases-fastcomp-536568644fd67d53778f6111fdd5f64ad3f4c539-64bit
           fastcomp-clang-e1.38.30-64bit
           fastcomp-clang-e1.38.31-64bit
    (*)    node-14.18.2-64bit           INSTALLED
           node-14.15.5-64bit
     *     python-3.9.2-nuget-64bit     INSTALLED
           python-3.9.2-64bit
     *     java-8.152-64bit             INSTALLED
           emscripten-1.38.30
           emscripten-1.38.31
           gnu-2.5.4
           mingw-7.1.0-64bit

The following tools can be compiled from source:
           llvm-git-main-32bit
           llvm-git-main-64bit      
           clang-tag-e1.38.30-32bit
           clang-tag-e1.38.31-32bit
           fastcomp-clang-tag-e1.38.30-64bit
           fastcomp-clang-tag-e1.38.31-64bit
           fastcomp-clang-master-32bit
           fastcomp-clang-master-64bit
           emscripten-tag-1.38.30-32bit
           emscripten-tag-1.38.31-32bit
           emscripten-tag-1.38.30-64bit
           emscripten-tag-1.38.31-64bit
           binaryen-tag-1.38.30-32bit
           binaryen-tag-1.38.31-32bit
           binaryen-tag-1.38.30-64bit
           binaryen-tag-1.38.31-64bit
           emscripten-main-32bit
           emscripten-main-64bit
           binaryen-main-32bit
           binaryen-main-64bit      
           ninja-git-release-64bit
           ccache-git-emscripten-64bit

Items marked with * are activated for the current user.
Items marked with (*) are selected for use, but your current shell environment is not configured to use them. Type "emsdk_env.bat" to set up your current shell to use them, or call "emsdk activate --permanent <name_of_sdk>" to permanently activate them.

To access the historical archived versions, type 'emsdk list --old'

Run "git pull" to pull in the latest list.
```

And running `git pull` says that I'm already up to date.

Not really sure what more I can do. I don't want to install a bunch of things manually because that sounds like a pain to update and emsdk really should be able to take care of installing and activating once it's setup properly.
Even if you don't know what the issue is, suggestions of what could possibly fix it are welcome.

Comment: IIRC there is an issue installing emsdk on Windows. Instead, I used WSL on Windows and install the package on Ubuntu. Using WSL on Windows is almost a requirement because other packages do not have Windows equivalents or are not tested very well on Windows. Using WSL simplifies finding solutions.

Comment: Can you show the full output of `emsdk_env.bat` when you it from a new terminal?

Also, the contents of `emsdk/.emscripten` would be useful too.